# Sieve in QGIS returns unexpected results

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, remote-sensing, raster-conversion

I have a rasterimage with values between 1 and 5.

[image: rf1]

I want to `sieve` it, using `QGIS - Raster - Analysis - Sieve`.

[image: rf2]

But then I get this:

[image: rf3]

The values changed. Even worse, when I color it, the whole raster image is one value.
The weird part, I created the image with an `R` script. When I `sieve` another output of the same `R` Script, it works...

What is going wrong?

Comment: Would you be able to give access to (part of) your rasterimage? This may help investigating. Note that the values you see in the legend of qgis are not necessarily correct, there can be other (no-data) values in your raster.